# interaction.options.getMember is not a function

Tags: discord.js

first time posting here. I hope I've posted this correctly, but basically getting the error message "interaction.options.getMember is not a function" I've tried using getUser as well (someone suggested this) and it doesnt seem to fix the problem. I'm pretty new to all this so please go easy on me. as far as I can see everything has been defined correctly and I'm pretty sure the issue is from here somewhere as the rest of the commands work absolutely fine. Any help greatly appreciated!!

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "Bans the target member",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    options: [
        {
            name: 'target',
            description: "Select a target to ban",
            type: "USER",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'reason',
            description: "Provide a reason for the ban",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'messages',
            description: "Choose one of the choices",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
            choices: [
                {
                    name: "Don't delete any",
                    value: "0"
                },
                {
                    name: "Previous 7 days",
                    value: "7"
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    execute(client, interaction) {

//ERROR IS LINE BELOW//
        const Target = interaction.options.getMember('target');

        if (Target.id === interaction.member.id)
        return interaction.followUp({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`⛔ You can't ban yourself.`)]})

        if (Target.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
        return interaction.followUp({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`⛔ You can't ban an administrator.`)]})

        const Reason = interaction.options.getString('reason');

        if (Reason.length > 512)
        return interaction.followUp({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`⛔ The reason cannot exceed 512 characters`)]})

        const Amount = interaction.options.getString('messages')
        Target.ban({days: Amount, reason: Reason})

        interaction.followUp({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("GREEN").setDescription(`✅ **${Target.user.username}** has been banned!`)]})

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `interaction` is actually a `Client` instance

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, and per Discord API, you have your member (actually user) here:

```js
 name: 'target',
 description: "Select a target to ban",
 type: "USER",
 required: true,
```

so that line should read

```js
const Target = interaction.options.getUser('target');
```

You need to get the `member` by using the below code

```js
const targetMember = interaction.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === Target)
```

The rest needs to change `Target` to `targetMember` or simplify with example below:

```js
if (targetMember.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS) || targetMember.user.bot || targetMember.user.id === interaction.user.id) {
    return interaction.reply({
    content: 'You are not authorized to ban this member or yourself.',
    ephemeral: true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to fix the issue before I went sleep at 4am. Essentially the problem was actually caused by the `execute (client, interaction)`. In my other file, these parameters are (interaction, client). I also changed all instances of "followUp" with "reply" and it started working as intended.

Thanks for helping out though!